# How to create controller method that is only available for users that are not authenticated?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2

So I know that you can create controller method that is only accesible if user is authenticated and has some role for example:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

adding this before controller method would make that method available only for user that has a role of Admin

I am wondering if it is possible to create a method that is only available for anonymous user (user that has not been authenticated) for example Registration method would be such method as I would not like to allow user that is already authenticated to create a new user?

TIA

Comment: This is just a wild shot but if you set a session variable when someone logs in you can check for that.

Comment: Yes, that might be a solution, but I am thinking if it can be done by adding something similar to [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] to the controller method.

Comment: For simplicity sake you could go with:  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a bit of googling it turns out denying access to someone is not that easy, you have to extend the AuthorizeAttribute class. You can read more in detail [here](http://lordzoltan.blogspot.ro/2012/09/adding-deny-functionality-to.html)